# how to add more filter condition in outlook current mailbox search box

Tags: outlook

[image]

as picture shows, i wanna add a more search condition like "subject" once click Search Current Mailbox in outlook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, i found the solution

1. select searching field
2. click "More"
3. select the common properties from list.

   [image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no trivial way to customize this window. Instead, I'd recommend using the `Advanced Find` method in Outlook:

[image]

The Outlook object model provides the `AdvancedSearch` method of the `Application` class which performs a search based on a specified DAV Searching and Locating (DASL) search string. The key benefits of using the `AdvancedSearch` method in Outlook are:

- The search is performed in another thread. You don’t need to run another thread manually since the AdvancedSearch method runs it automatically in the background.
- Possibility to search for any item types: mail, appointment, calendar, notes etc. in any location, i.e. beyond the scope of a certain folder. The `Restrict` and `Find`/`FindNext` methods can be applied to a particular `Items` collection (see the `Items` property of the `Folder` class in Outlook).
- Full support for DASL queries (custom properties can be used for searching too). You can read more about this in the [Filtering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208216%28v=office.12%29) article in MSDN. To improve the search performance, Instant Search keywords can be used if Instant Search is enabled for the store (see the `IsInstantSearchEnabled` property of the Store class).
- You can stop the search process at any moment using the `Stop` method of the `Search` class.